# Web view is not loading for particular url

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I am trying to load webview for the following url http://www.topchickw.com/ but blank screen occured but same code is working for other url's

```
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.topchickw.com/"];
NSURLRequest *myUrlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
[self.myWebView loadRequest:myUrlRequest];
```

Can any one suggest me how to load webview of the particular url
  Thanks in Advance

Comment: I can't open this URL here. Have you tried the same link in the mobile safari?

Comment: yeah...At the very first time the site too not respond in safari but after installing flash player it opens.Like that is their any solution to open the particular url

Answer (score 6):

I am not an HTML expert. It seems that the URL when loaded is playing a flash video (`.swf` file). iOS does not support flash. Hence the blank screen.

[image]

To cross check this I try opening the URL in mobile safari browser, it did not work.

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer, more details about flash and iOS here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_and_Adobe_Flash_controversy

Answer (score 0):

Well this url if you open manually in browser you will get blank window only. Please check the issue is not in the code.

Answer (score 0):

A flash file runs when this url is loaded into browser. The issue is not with code but with the website as iOS doesnot support flash.

Comment: I know code is fine but is their any solution to load flash in iphone.At the very first time i try to open in safari web browser it shows blank black screen.After downlaoded the flash player it's working fine Like wise Let me know is their any solution

Comment: I am sure the video is running on your safari web browser, but iOS doesnot support flash. therefore one way to check this is to use your iOS safari in your iphone and try to open the url there. See that it will not work there and there is no flash support for iPhone as well.